# Hiding/Showing a NavigationBar on iphone rotate gives disorientated NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, device-orientation

I have a weird one which I hope someone can help with. 
I have an app which when I rotate to landscape, I hide the NavigationBar...

```
-(void)willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
if( toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait )
    {
        self.view = portraitView;

    }
    else if( toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft )
    {
        self.view = landscapeRightView;
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    }
```

This works OK and the NavBar disappears.  The problem is, when I rotate back to portrait, my NavBar reappears, but is vertical in the middle of my view, not horizontal at the top of the screen!!!  No matter where I put the re-appearance of the NavBar (after rotation, after first half), it is alway in wrong orientation and place when coming back to portrait view.

Here is my code on rotation back to portrait:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
if( self.view == portraitView )
{
     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}
}
```

Can anyone offer ideas? This is driving me crazy!

Comment: Did you fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

check both

> if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait  || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
>
> {
>   }
>   else if(interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
>
> {
>   }

Comment: ...thanks but don't see what good that does. The problem is re-showing the NavBar on return to Portrait. The NavBar appear 90 degrees out down centre of screen